# GO言語のanacondaで送られてきたリプライに返信する方法

Tags: go, twitter

UserStreamで相手からのリプライを検知する所まではできたのですが、そこからどうやってそのリプライに返信するかが分かりません。anacondaのGoDocなどもざっと見ましたがそれらしき物を見つける事ができませんでした。
どうすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anaconda に限った話ではないですが一般的に twitter API でリプライを作るには `in_reply_to_status_id` パラメータを使用します。

```
v := url.Values{}
v.Add("in_reply_to_status_id", 発言元ツイートのID)
tweet, _ := api.PostTweet("@stenpel ないわー", v)
```

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます！